# Can scrapy start_request not yield or return?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scraper which I want to check the url before calling http request and parsing. The url might be `None` since it is an input arg to the call:

```
    def start_requests(self):
    # url as input to system
    
    if url:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

From the docs the `start_request` function must return an iterable of Requests. The above code works without returning any items if `url` is `None`. Is this bad practice for scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

What [scrapy does](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py#L117) with that is

```
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
```

It works because of `yield` keyword. This changes return type to generator, so even if `url` is None, empty generator will be returned and that's why it works (and is perfectly fine). But be careful, if you decide to use list:

```
def start_requests(self):
    # url as input to system
    
    if url:
        return [scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)]
```

It will break.